# execution of Dispatcher.BeginInvoke ends when reaches await statement

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, async-await, webrequest, dispatcher

Following code is executed in ScheduledAgent on WindowsPhone device, but for the reason that I do not know, execution ends when reaches this line:

```
col = await wl.GetModelsAsync(day, 1, mgr.LastCountryPath, Resolution.PhoneResolutions[3]);
```

this method calls the method below and execution ends on 2nd line of that method.

```
public async Task<Stream> DownloadAsync(string url)
{
    WebRequest rq = WebRequest.Create(url);
    WebResponse rp = await Task.Factory.FromAsync<WebResponse>(rq.BeginGetResponse, rq.EndGetResponse, null);
    return rp.GetResponseStream();
}
```

All the code was working properly until today, but as far as I remember, I haven't changed much.

```
Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((async () =>
{
    List<WallpaperModel> col;
    try
    {
        int day = 0;
        if (mgr.ImageMode == WallpaperChangeMode.RandomMode)
        {
            Random r = new Random();
            day = r.Next(16);
        }
        col = await wl.GetModelsAsync(day, 1, mgr.LastCountryPath, Resolution.PhoneResolutions[3]);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        NotifyComplete();
        return;
    }
    Stream s = await wl.DownloadAsync(col[0].Image.UriSource.OriginalString);
    var hlpr = new LockHelper(s);
    await hlpr.TrySetLockAsync(true);

}));
```

Comment: Does it always stop? or just sometimes?

Comment: It ends each and every time, although It used to work

Comment: I could also do without Dispatcher here, but I do not want to write new code only for this case.

Comment: Are you using BeginInvoke only to update the col property?

Comment: I am using Dispatcher to create BitmapImage. Which I do not use later in this case, but I didn't want to rewrite method to just return collection of image urls and not collection of models what it does now. Beside that, I do not understand why Dispatcher.BeginInvoke does not execute at all (if I want to dispatch just the creation of bitmap itself)

Comment: Try not mixing async-await with the Dispatcher. Do what you have to do on the UI thread and use await to leave the UI thread for non UI tasks.

Answer (score 1):

Try awaiting on InvokeAsync instead of BeginInvoke:

```
await Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync((async () =>
{
    List<WallpaperModel> col;
    try
    {
        int day = 0;
        if (mgr.ImageMode == WallpaperChangeMode.RandomMode)
        {
            Random r = new Random();
            day = r.Next(16);
        }
        col = await wl.GetModelsAsync(day, 1, mgr.LastCountryPath, Resolution.PhoneResolutions[3]);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        NotifyComplete();
        return;
    }

    Stream s = await wl.DownloadAsync(col[0].Image.UriSource.OriginalString);
    var hlpr = new LockHelper(s);
    await hlpr.TrySetLockAsync(true);

}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Dispatcher.BeginInvoke() basically adds commands(adding textblock text ect..) to the Ui thread Queue. await if fruitful when you use it on threads/Tasks. even though you use await on Dispatcher.BeginInvoke() its not gonna do anything except it just adds the content of the deleage to the Ui Thread.

i would suggest put all your business logic in the thread and await the thread. once your thread gets executed successfully, use dispatcher to update the UI thread.

basically don't mix up your task/thread and dispatcher.